# Does ItextSharp 5.4.5 support 256 bit encryption?

Tags: .net, itext

Does ItextSharp 5.4.5 support 256 bit encryption ??

i did my research but didn't find anything about 256 bit encryption. All people are saying itext java version support AES 256 bit encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here's a short example that takes a PDF and encrypts a copy of it using 256-bit AES encryption:

```
var openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
openDialog.DefaultExt = "pdf";
if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    using (var input = openDialog.OpenFile())
    {
        var saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveDialog.DefaultExt = "pdf";
        if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            using (var reader = new PdfReader(input)) 
            {
                using (var output = saveDialog.OpenFile())
                {
                    PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(\
                        reader, output, 
                        PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_256, 
                        "password", "password", 
                        PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can iTextSharp then open that encrypted file afterwards? I am getting error "Unknown encryption type R=6" in v5.5.9 when trying to open a PDF w/ 256-bit encryption.